# Как "перевернуть" столбец если данные в нем зеркальны к другому столбцу?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть два столбца в [фрейме данных](https://dropmefiles.com/kCLLA). Данные столбца `df['final']` зеркальны по отношению к `df['1']`.

А как их преобразовать, или так сказать, перевернуть, чтобы они не были зеркальны а были более коррелированы?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('regr2.csv')
df
```

```
Date          1        final
1/3/2020    155990  62663615.65
1/3/2020    156090  62643374.18
1/3/2020    156350  62605822.13
1/3/2020    156400  62659019.66
1/3/2020    156610  62654704.55
1/3/2020    156600  62654718.59
1/3/2020    156550  62656798.91
```

То есть, как видите данные из `df['final']` на графике зеркальны по отношению к `df['1']`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После преобразования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
x = np.linspace(4, 10, 100)

y = np.sin(x**2)*np.random.rand(len(x))*np.exp(x)

plt.plot(x, y)

# "зеркальный" график
plt.plot(x, y.mean() - y)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]